# how to send email in reactjs app using sendgrid

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sendgrid

I'm sending emails via contact form using sendgrid. It works fin in the localhost with port 3001. how to use my domain in the fetch with port value. can someone help?

this is the code for button click

`````
        const { email } = this.state
        fetch(`http://domain.in:3001/contactus/send-email?recipient=${email.recipient}&sender=${email.sender}&topic=${email.subject}&text=${email.text}`)
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("error ", err);
            })
        this.setState({ email: { ...email, subject: '', sender: '', text: '' } })

    }````

--------> this is on server.js <-----------

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

sgMail.setApiKey('*******************')
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the Sendgrid Email server');
})
app.get('/contactus/send-email', (req, res) => {
    const { recipient, sender, topic, text } = req.query
    console.log("came ");

    const msg = {
        to: recipient,
        from: sender,
        subject: topic,
        text: text
    }
    sgMail.send(msg).then((msg) => {
        console.log(text);
    })
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
`````

Comment: wait, I don't think you need the `http://domain.in:3001` in your fetch call. I believe simply having `/contactus/send-email?YOUR_QUERY_PARAMS` would work.

Comment: :( that didnt work

Comment: what's the error that you are getting?